# Overlay two rasters with different CRS in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, raster, coordinate-systems

I have two rasters, first Landsat8 in WGS84, second Euro-Cordex with rotated lon and lat.

**Landsat8** with bounds  (18.59485688668886, 49.1151186646496, 18.87809569577174, 49.30106992846235)

```
ls='C:/...../Landsat8.nc'
LS= xr.open_dataset(ls, decode_coords="all")
LS=LS['band_data']
LS.plot()
```

[image]

**Euro-Cordex** with bounds (0.2800000061591466, -1.7600000500679016, 0.7200000236431757, -1.0999999642372131)

```
ec='C:/....../ECZA.tif'
#EC= xr.open_dataset(ec, decode_coords="all")
EC= xr.open_dataset(ec)
EC=EC["band_data"]
EC=EC[7]
EC.plot()
```

[image]

When I plot them in the Qgis they are at the same location.

I want to overlay them in the Python, and Clip by the Landsat8.

I try the change the Euro-Cordex to WGS 84 but it did not work.

Please, do you have any ideas, on how to change Cordex coordinates to WGS84 or any other approach? Thanks.

[Here you can find the data ECZA and LandSat](https://github.com/MartinKAJO/Euro-Cordex.git)

I tried this, but I get an error: ValueError: IndexVariable objects must be 1-dimensional

```
EC84=EC.rio.reproject('epsg:4326', inplace = True)
EC84

ValueError: IndexVariable objects must be 1-dimensional
```

So I tried to change the name of the coordination from rlon,rlat to x,y

```
EC84=EC84.rename({'rlon':'x', 'rlat':'y'})
```

But I still got the same ValueError.

However, I figure it out with:

```
EC84=EC2.rio.reproject_match(LS)
```